# Event emmission doesn't work io.sockets.emit()

Tags: node.js, sockets, events, socket.io, emit

Tried to emit an event for entire socket connection and all the clients connected to the socket. 
used,

```
io.sockets.emit('toALL',{msg: 'this is demo'});
```

and handled it in `index.html` with following line of code:

```
socket.on("toALL",function(){
   // If console is putted here still not able to get any msg or response from emit. 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution from: https://socket.io/get-started/chat#Integrating-Socket-IO

For ***server.js:***

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.on('toALL', function(msg){
     io.emit('toALL', msg);
   });
 });
```

For Client.html

```
socket.emit('toALL', 'event');
    socket.on('toALL', function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you've sent to the socket is available as the parameter to the callback function for `.on`. You can use `io.emit` to broadcast to all clients.

```
// server
io.emit("toALL", {msg: "this is demo"});
```

```
// client
socket.on("toALL", function (msg) {
  console.log(msg); 
});
```

Comment: at client side do I need to invoke function connect() with url with prefix http? I am running my server on http and used, `var socket = io()` at client side, **client.html** file.

Comment: Not necessarily--if you don't provide an argument, it assumes same domain, which may or may not be what you need. If it can't connect you should get an error (which you should share with us).